# How do I use environment variables in Supervisord's [supervisord] config section?

Tags: supervisord

I use environment variables in Supervisord's program section, and they work just fine:

```
[program:some_prog]
command=%(ENV_env_var_name)s/...
```

I can't figure out though how to do the same in the [supervisord] section.
I tried using the same syntax with and without the ENV_ prefix, but getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/supervisord", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('supervisor==3.0a12', 'console_scripts', 'supervisord')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a12-py2.7.egg/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 356, in main
    options.realize(args, doc=__doc__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a12-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 419, in realize
    Options.realize(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a12-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 284, in realize
    self.process_config_file()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a12-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 478, in process_config_file
    Options.process_config_file(self, do_usage=do_usage)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a12-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 292, in process_config_file
    self.read_config(self.configfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a12-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 527, in read_config
    section.directory = existing_directory(directory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor-3.0a12-py2.7.egg/supervisor/datatypes.py", line 336, in existing_directory
    nv = v % {'here':here}
KeyError: 'var_name'
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 9):

Supervisor only supports expansions with environment variables in a limited number of locations, each of which is documented in the [configuration documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html).

Unfortunately, the `[supervisord]` `directory` option is not one of those; it only supports the `%(here)` variable, nothing else.

You could file a feature request for this in the [supervisord issue tracker](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues) if this an important issue for you.

In my projects, we generally use [zc.buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) to make deployment and development environment setup predictable and repeatable, and generate the supervisor configuration from a template. There is a [specialized buildout recipe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.supervisor/) to make this task easier.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn. Apparently there is already a feature request open in the [supervisord issue tracker](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/126)

Comment: So there is; you could leave a comment with your specific use-case perhaps, to illustrate the usefulness of the feature.

Comment: The feature has been merged since June 2014; interestingly, release 3.2 is yet to be released and it's been a year since last release.